# Would this be a bad use case of Apache Camel?

Tags: web-services, apache-camel

We are implementing a Web Service using Apache Camel that has many (20-50) "direct:" routes calling Java methods.  Every method basically has a route to it, whether it's for business rule processing, or DAO access methods.  All the routes use `from("direct:").to("direct")`, but never to any other component.

While this may seem like it decouples the system from the standard Controller->bo->dao layers, it adds unnecessary book keeping of the Camel routes.

A better alternative would just simply be to define Java interfaces for the Business Objects and Dao layers, with an additional interface for any other service (external to the system, like `file://`, or `http://`) requests that would be a dependency inside the Business Objects or Controllers.  The implementation to this additional interface would be using Apache Camel to talk to those external services.

As a side note, I'm thinking about how to convince my current colleagues to see my point.

Thoughts?

tldr;
Should Apache Camel be used where there is only 1 or 2 applications present?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Unfortunately your question is waaay too vague for this format - see [Is Stack Overflow a forum?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/195481). To ask a question here you really need to have a specific problem that you're looking for a solution to, rather than a topic for discussion.

Comment: Hey, sorry if I've caused offense - there are a lot of people who leave pretty cold messages on here, and I try to add a little personality to mine to avoid that, but that can wind up coming off hostile. The reason I say that this question isn't a good fit for the site is that it could probably be argued either way - these kinds of things can be very situational. Far better to give more detail and get a better answer. As you point out though, this is not my specialty so I may be wrong. I have spent more than 10 years programming, however, so I do have *some* idea what I'm talking about.

Comment: I think the question might be clearer with a code example (e.g. showing a simplified path taken by one typical message through the whole system) ; also, it would almost certainly be a better fit for [programmers.se](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I have used applications where there have been 20 systems involved in various complexity, protocols and patterns. I know other places where 50+ systems are involved. The only limit is on your design, performance etc.

Apache Camel is a middleware framework. Essentially your business logic should not know about how the data got to it or where it is to be delivered, only what it should deliver. Camel should take care of the rest.

By the way, does your middleware not talk to the external world? Why only use the `direct` and not other components?

You can also hide the middleware by using bean integration. That gives you an even more decoupling. See here: http://camel.apache.org/bean-integration.html

It really depends on what it is you want to accomplish and what your requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for your specific use case I would say that you would probably have been better off with just a regular Java implementation with Camel being used as a glue between your system and the outside world. Like [Souciance explains in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39567232/4657798), Camel really shines when you have to integrate with multiple systems so you should at least keep it for communicating with the outside-world.

However, having already implemented the system's internals using Camel, I would have to say that it doesn't make much sense to put additional effort into replacing it with pure Java, especially since the current implementation gives you the ability to make the system more robust, for instance by using a high-performance MQ as a replacement for the `direct` routes, which would help your system become more resistant to failures and more easily decoupled later on, not to mention that having routes around your DAO objects makes it much easier to implement batching of DB updates when your system's load grows.